# sphinx - set weight to a doc in a query

Tags: search, sphinx, pagerank

In sphinx search, is that possible set weight or pr somelike to specified record(@id) for corresponding query keyword? What i expect to do is raise/decrease some **specified rank of records** for **specified queries**. eg:doc A has 2 weights for 2 different words

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is **Payloads**
http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#conf-sql-joined-field

you attach specific weights to words in a document.

Comment: thx!,it seems to be the right way, is there an alternative in old version which dosent support?